# Как запихнуть массив mysql в jquery

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Как вместо ActionScript, AppleScript и тд вставить данные из mysqli вот это

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users");
$myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$myrow['login'];//вот это должно вывести
```

вот и сам Jquery код

```js
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: как выглядит формат данных который возврщает запрос к `mysqli`?

Comment: @VyacheslavDanshin Простите? Можно как нибудь попонятнее

Comment: @VyacheslavDanshin возвращает текст если я правильно понял

Comment: видимо вы выполняете код на стороне сервера, который получает данные из БД, и хотите эти данные втавить на фронте в "ui-widget", я правильно понимаю? тогда для этого вам необходимо сделать запрос на сервер и обработать от него ответ, и пока я не понимаю в каком формате сервер вернет вам данные я не могу написать вам код клиента по биндингу этих данных в виджет.

Comment: @VyacheslavDanshin так что вам написать что бы Вы помогли мне?

Comment: формат данных ответа сервера на запрос клиента

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46509/discussion-between-bedomar-and-vyacheslav-danshin).

Comment: @VyacheslavDanshin а как это узнать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прямо "в лоб" и пихайте, если переменная доступна для файла где JS:

```
$( function() {
    var availableTags = <?php $myrow['login'] ?>
}
```

возможно придется перебрать циклом если это php-массив:

```
$( function() {
    var availableTags =

        <?php
        foreach ($myrow['login'] as $login) {
            echo $login.',';
        }
        ?>;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

нажми выполнить и попробуй ввести что то латиницей, будут предложены варианты репозиториев google

```js
$( function() {        
  var availableTags = [];
  $.get( "http://api.github.com/users/google/repos", function( data ) {
    data.forEach(function(item) {
      availableTags.push(item.name);
    })
  });

  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

[документация по jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Comment: а как нужно заносить данные в файл с тегами

Comment: @BedOmar какой файл с тегами??? вы спросили как вам вставить данные в виджет, я ответил на ваш вопрос. Примените это к вашей ситуации, я же объяснил что нужно сделать запрос на сервер который ответит необходимыми вам данными, но вы упорно отказываетесь предоставить формат ответа вашего сервера и я привел вам пример как реализовать это на фронте без этих данных. Или вы хотите что бы я написал за вас еще и серверную часть?

Comment: если можно то подалуйсто напишыте и серверную)